# Are the two groups isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G,H,K$ be three groups. If $G\times H$ is isomorphic to $G\times K$, then is it true for $H\cong K$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Also this question has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, take

$$G=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\cdots$$
$$H=\mathbb{Z}$$
$$K=1$$

Note that the thesis holds if $G$ is finite (Hirshon's theorem). See [here](https://chiasme.wordpress.com/2014/11/29/cancellation-property-for-groups-i/).

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a counterexample where all 3 groups are finite?

Comment: @Aaron No, the thesis holds for finite groups.

Comment: Thank you for the link, that's quite interesting.

Comment: Thank you, I understood.

Answer (score -1):

Let $A=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n$, where $G_n=\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n$.
And then we have $\mathbb{Z}\times A\cong\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times A$. But $\mathbb{Z}\ncong\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.